# Spring: ResponseBodyEmitter.CompleteWithError() and global exception handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have async controller method in Spring, that uses ResponseBodyEmitter to download file asynchronously.

```
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter> download() {
     ResponseBodyEmitter emitter = new ResponseBodyEmitter();
     taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
      try {
       emitter.send(contentProducer.produce())
       emitter.complete()
      } catch(ContentProducerException e) {
       emitter.completeWithError(e)
      }
     }
     return new ResponseEntity<>(emitter, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I have a global exception handler that deals with ContentProducerException and responds with Internal Server Error.

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = ContentProducerException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(final ContentProducerException e, final WebRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("error", headers, httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

However, when contentProducer throws ContentProducerException and completeWithError() is being called the following things happen:

- global handler handleException() is called to no effect
- response is 200 and browser downloads empty file

Please help me understand what is happening and how can I properly return 500 in this case (instead of 200 and invalid file download).

Answer (score 0):

`taskExecutor.execute` is set to be asynchronous in another thread. Your method schedules the tasks then returns with the 200. It doesn't wait for the task to be executed before returning. From the spring documentation

> **execute**
>
> ```
> void execute(java.lang.Runnable task)
>
> Execute the given task.
>
> The call might return immediately if the implementation uses an asynchronous execution strategy, or might block in the case of synchronous execution.
>
> Specified by:
>     execute in interface java.util.concurrent.Executor
> Parameters:
>     task - the Runnable to execute (never null)
> Throws:
>     TaskRejectedException - if the given task was not accepted
> ```

You should be able to modify your code to wait like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter> download() throws Exception {
     ResponseBodyEmitter emitter = new ResponseBodyEmitter();
     Future<Void> task = taskExecutor.submit(() -> {
      try {
       emitter.send(contentProducer.produce())
       emitter.complete()
      } catch(ContentProducerException e) {
       emitter.completeWithError(e)
      }
     }
     task.get();
     return new ResponseEntity<>(emitter, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

`get()` Will wait for the task to complete before continuing which is what you want.

Comment: But what is a good approach to handle exceptions in this case?

Comment: Download the file in the same thread so it is synchronous and throw the error when needed

Comment: Does sync mean I do not need ResponseBodyEmitter then?

Comment: Could be, what you want is a synchronous way to download the file because the method will return status 200 if you do it asynchronously

Comment: Can I keep controller method asynchronous, but wait with responding to client until the background processing is finished (not to block the request thread)? Does Spring allow this?

Comment: See my edit.  You should be able to modify what you have to make it `submit` instead of execute. `submit` returns a `Future` Then you can call `get()` on that `Future` to make it wait.

Comment: Can Spring await on Future without blocking? Instead of calling get() explicitly?

Comment: The thread wont be blocked from other people calling download. the .get() will be for the current session for the person who called it. Others who call it wont be blocked from downloading.

Comment: Yes, I understand, can I implement it in a non-blocking way, however not returning to the client before the processing is complete?

Comment: Possibly but without knowing the full extend or seeing your full code it would be hard to say. Unless there is an absolute need to have it not bock, I'd suggest trying what I posted first to see if that will work for your needs.